# after submit redirect to the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I am using smoothscroll navigation, like this:

```
 <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
```

And I have a contact form, like this:

```
<section id="contact" class="text-center">




    @using (Html.BeginForm("contact","Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <section id="contact" class="text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="2000">
                        <h3>CONTACT Microrout.nl</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">

                        Microrout.nl
                        <br />frederik hendriklaan 253-b
                        <br />Den Haag
                        <br />0641697144


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromEmail)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input type="submit" value="SHOOT MESSAGE" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @*<div class="google_map">
                    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                </div>*@


        </section>
    }






</section>
```

and this are the Contact methods:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(EmailFormModel model)
        {
            string message2 = "There are a few errors";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {


                    message2 = "Thanks! We'll get back to you soon.";
                    var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
                    var message = new MailMessage();
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("nengelen@online.nl")); //replace with valid value
                    message.Subject = "Your email subject";
                    message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);

                    }



                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error sending email: " + error.Message + "<br /> StackTrace: " + error.StackTrace);
                }
                ViewBag.Message = "Thank you for contact us";
                //return new RedirectToActionAnchor("Contact", "", "#contact");

            }

            //if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            //{
            //    return new JsonResult { Data = new { success = true, message = message2 } };
            //}

            //TempData["Message"] = message2;


            return View(model);
        }
```

But how to return back to the contact form, after submit, because after the submit the url changed to:

```
http://localhost:53534/Home/contact
```

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(EmailFormModel model)
        {
            string message2 = "There are a few errors";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {


                    message2 = "Thanks! We'll get back to you soon.";
                    var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
                    var message = new MailMessage();
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("nengelen@online.nl")); //replace with valid value
                    message.Subject = "Your email subject";
                    message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);

                    }



                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error sending email: " + error.Message + "<br /> StackTrace: " + error.StackTrace);
                }
                ViewBag.Message = "Thank you for contact us";
                //return new RedirectToActionAnchor("Contact", "", "#contact");

            }

            //if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            //{
            //    return new JsonResult { Data = new { success = true, message = message2 } };
            //}

            //TempData["Message"] = message2;


            return View("Contact",model);
        }
```

but the problem is that it then goes to: `http://localhost:53534/Home/contact`

But the Url of Contact is:`http://localhost:53534/#contact`

And this is my navigation:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">STUDIO</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#team" class="smoothScroll">TEAM</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#service" class="smoothScroll">SERVICES</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#work" class="smoothScroll">WORK</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#pricing" class="smoothScroll">PRICING</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">CONTACT</a></li>
                            @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")
                            </li>*@
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

This is my Home controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }



        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(EmailFormModel model)
        {
            string message2 = "There are a few errors";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {


                    message2 = "Thanks! We'll get back to you soon.";
                    var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
                    var message = new MailMessage();
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("nengelen@online.nl")); //replace with valid value
                    message.Subject = "Your email subject";
                    message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);

                    }



                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error sending email: " + error.Message + "<br /> StackTrace: " + error.StackTrace);
                }
                ViewBag.Message = "Thank you for contact us";
                //return new RedirectToActionAnchor("Contact", "", "#contact");

            }

            //if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            //{
            //    return new JsonResult { Data = new { success = true, message = message2 } };
            //}

            //TempData["Message"] = message2;


            return View("Home",model);
        }
    }
```

it seems that if I use this:return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl("Home") + "#contact"); the anchor(#) will be skipped

Comment: Replace return View(model); With View("ViewName",model);

Comment: `return View(model);` does return to the same view. And of course the url is `/Home/contact` What are you expecting/wanting it to be?

Comment: Hi PM thank you for your answare, I updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a view, return a redirect:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

As you also want to jump to an anchor on the page, you can use the following:

```
return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl("Index") + "#contact");
```

This is the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://www.talksharp.com/what-is-the-post-redirect-get-pattern) pattern, which ensures you can't double-submit an action.  However, in this case you will lose the information in your `ViewBag.Message`.

Comment: Hi Richard, that is better, but now it redirects to the top of the page(Index) and it doenst go back to the section Contact(bottom of the page) of Index

Comment: Updated to include jumping to #contact

Comment: I tryed , but it still jumps to the top of index. The url after sumbit is also: http://localhost:53534/ , so it skips the #contact

Comment: Hi Richard, I got this error:A route named 'Home' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: A route named 'Home' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name

Source Error: 


Line 134:
Line 135:
Line 136:            return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl("Home") + "#contact");
Line 137:        }
Line 138:    }

Comment: Hi Richard, the url skps every time the anchor(#), after submit

Comment: ah, this was doing the right work:  return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("") + "#contact"); thx Richard, you put me on the right path

Comment: Sorry, should've been Index!

Comment: Any ideas how to pass model through this redirect? I have the same problem but I need to pass the model with the #contact anchor. Thanks.